# TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices

Hola compañeros me podrían decir porque me aparece error:

> TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Cuando agrego en lista 3 las posiciones.

Y otra cosa: siempre que saco primos me funcionan bien los programas pero siempre que voy a sacar primos en una matriz me dice que el 1 es primo y esto hace que el programa no funcione como debería ser.

Aquí mi código:

```
"""32.  Leer una matriz 3x3 entera y determinar en qué posiciones están los menores primos por fila"""

try:

    matriz=[]
    fil=0
    columna=0


    for a in range(3):
        fila=[]
        for b in range(3):
            numeros=int(input("Digite un numero entero: "))
            fila.append(numeros)
        matriz.append(fila)   #almaceno los numeros digitados en matriz

    lista2=[]
    lista3=[]
    for c in range(len(matriz)):
        menor=matriz[c][0]
        for d in range(len(matriz[c])):
            primo=matriz[c][d]

            cont=0
            for e in range(1,primo+1):
                if (primo%e)==0:
                    cont+=1

            if cont==2:
                primo_menor=primo      #determino si el numero es primo

                if primo_menor<=menor:
                    menor=primo_menor
                    fil=c
                    columna=d
        lista2.append(primo_menor) # al numero menor primo de cada fila lo almaceno aquí
        lista3.append(columna,fil) #y almaceno las posiciones(columa,fila) de los primos menores

    print("La matriz es:",matriz)
    print("los primos menores de cada fila son:",lista2)
    print("Y estan en las posiciones",lista3)

except ValueError:

    print("El valor digitado debe ser numerico")
```

Comment: Append espera como único argumento una lista con los elementos a añadir. Es decir, debes usar `lista3.append([columna, fil])`. Respecto al primo, yo reduciría el rango que tienes entre (1, primo+1) a (2, primo). De hecho, puedes reducirlo aún más, hasta la raiz cuadrada del primo. La condición sería entonces que cont fuese 0. Pero también puedes salir del bucle tan pronto como encuentras un divisor, en lugar de contarlos, pues en ese caso no es primo.

Comment: muchísimas gracias he estado todo el día con este código tratándolo de resolver por mi cuenta antes de preguntar

Comment: Amigo asi reduzca el rango siempre me sigue diciendo que el 1 es primo que me aconsejas? hago otra forma de sacar primos o aun puedo corregir algo para que funcione de esta manera?

Comment: No sé si ya conoces las funciones, pero creo que todo quedaría más limpio y legible si escribes una función llamada `es_primo()` al que le pases el número y te retorne `True` o  `False`. La función comenzaría por mirar si el número recibido es 1 y retornaría `False` o 2 y retornaría `True`. En otro caso iteraría por los enteros menores o iguales a su raiz cuadrada, comenzando en 2 y tan pronto como encuentre un divisor, retorna `False`. Si llega al final del bucle sin haber  encontrado divisores, retorna `True`. Usarías esa función en el principal asi: `if es_primo(numero)`

Answer (score 0):

Remplaza:

```
lista3.append(columna,fil)
```

Por:

```
lista3.append([columna,fil])
```

Y ya esta:

Has convertido dos argumentos:

1. columna
2. fil en uno: `[columna, fil]`

La delimitación con corchetes convierte a los dos en UN conjunto.